# Update Record Field in callout fired from an AfterUpdate Trigger

Tags: trigger, callout, dml, future, update

So I have a Trigger on Account, on the AfterUpdate event (I've also tried on BeforeUpdate), it launches a SOAP Request to a WebService (via a @future method), and this WebService returns a number that I need to assign on this account record (it's an External Id).

The problem is, I can't use DML because it's firing from a Trigger, I can't return this field since it's a @future method and must be void and I also can't access to Trigger.new or Trigger.newMap (they are null on the future method)

I still don't get why I can't fire an update DML statement if I'm already checking for recursiveness on my Trigger Helper.

Any Ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some assumptions here that you can work around.

> The problem is, I can't use DML because it's firing from a Trigger, I can't return this field since it's a @future method and must be void and I also can't access to Trigger.new or Trigger.newMap (they are null on the future method)

The future method can in fact perform DML.  The future method is running in a separate transaction; it has no access to the trigger context variables, but if you provide the Id as a parameter, it can perform DML on the original Account.

> I still don't get why I can't fire an update DML statement if I'm already checking for recursiveness on my Trigger Helper.

I think your concern is that your future method will re-invoke the trigger when it performs DML. You can work around this with a simple guard structure: place a static Boolean variable `shouldSuppressCallout` in your trigger handler class, and code your handler not to make the future call if it's set to `true`.

Then, in your future method, set it to `true` before you perform update DML, and reset it to `false` afterwards.

You don't specify how exactly your recursion guard is implemented, but be aware that recursion guards based on static Booleans with a method like `runOnce()` are bad patterns that cause a lot of subtle problems in trigger operation. However, in the future method, all of your statics have reset because you're in a separate transaction, so it may not behave the way you're expecting it to.